# I want to draw a circle on an image in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to draw a white circle on an image when the mouse is on the image. so I made this function.
But when I act this, that image is just loaded without circle. 
Can you help me?

```
def imgbutton(name, size, x, y):
  active = False
  (mx, my) = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

  img = pygame.image.load(name)
  transimg = pygame.transform.scale(img, size)
  imgrect = transimg.get_rect()
  imgrect.topleft = x, y
  cpos = imgrect.center
  size = w, h

  if (w > mx > x) and (h > my > y):
      active = True
      pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,255,255), cpos, 20, 5)

  screen.blit(transimg, imgrect)
  return active
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circle and the image are drawn on `screen`. If you draw the circle before the image, then the image covers the circle. You have to draw the circle after the image:

```py
def imgbutton(name, size, x, y):
  # [...]

  screen.blit(transimg, imgrect)
  if (w > mx > x) and (h > my > y):
      active = True
      pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,255,255), cpos, 20, 5)

  # [...]
```